# Outputting Pascal's triangle

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, formatting, ghc, io-monad

```
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import System.IO

-- I love how amazingly concise Haskell code can be.  This same program in C, C++ or Java
-- would be at least twice as long.


pascal :: Int -> Int -> Int
pascal row col | col >= 0 && col <= row =
                 if row == 0 || col == 0 || row == col
                 then 1
                 else pascal (row - 1) (col - 1) + pascal (row - 1) col
pascal _ _ = 0


pascalsTriangle :: Int -> [[Int]]
pascalsTriangle rows =
  [[pascal row col | col <- [0..row]] | row <- [0..rows]]


main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "" 
  putStr "Starting at row #0, how many rows of Pascal's Triangle do you want to print out? "
  hFlush stdout
  numRows <- (\s -> read s :: Int) <$> getLine
  let triangle = pascalsTriangle numRows
      triangleOfStrings = map (intercalate ", ") $ map (map show) triangle
      lengthOfLastDiv2 = div ((length . last) triangleOfStrings) 2 
  putStrLn ""
  mapM_ (\s -> let spaces = [' ' | x <- [1 .. lengthOfLastDiv2 - div (length s) 2]]
                   in (putStrLn $ spaces ++ s) >> threadDelay 200000) triangleOfStrings
  putStrLn ""
```

My little program above finds the values of Pascal's Triangle.  But if you compile it and use it you'll see that the "triangle" looks more like a Christmas tree than a triangle!  Ouch!

I'm just taking half the length of the last line and subtracting from that half the length of each preceding line, and creating that many blank spaces to add to the beginning of each string.  It ALMOST works, but I'm looking for an equilateral triangle type of effect, but to me it resembles a sloping Christmas tree!  Is there a better way to do this.  What am I missing besides some programming talent?!  Thanks for the help.  THIS IS NOT A HOMEWORK ASSIGNMENT.  I'm just doing this for fun and recreation.  I appreciate the help.

Best.
Douglas Lewit.

Comment: The reason it visually thins towards the top is that the numbers there are smaller. A simple workaround is to pad all numbers with spaces to have the same width, before putting them together.

Comment: BTW, computing pascal numbers this way is super inefficient, because the recursive calls aren't shared. I recommend memoising `pascal`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, better would be to implement `pascalsTriangle` directly, and perhaps to implement `pascal` using that. There's probably a more efficient direct implementation of `pascal` out there too. Oh, and there's symmetry to use, though I'm not sure it's a win to do so.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Those are just binomial coefficients, which can be computed using a multiplicative formula. For the whole triangle, it's still surely best to calculate directly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a straightforward implementation:

```
space n = replicate n ' '

pad n s | n < length s = take n s
pad n s = space (n - length s) ++ s

triangle = iterate (\ xs -> zipWith (+) (xs ++ [0]) (0:xs)) [1]

rowPrint n hw xs  = space (n * hw) ++ concatMap (pad (2*hw) . show) xs

triRows n hw = [rowPrint (n-i) hw row | (i,row) <- zip [1..n] triangle]

main = do
  s <- getLine
  mapM_ putStrLn (triRows (read s) 2)
```

Note that `triangle` is an infinite Pascal's triangle, generated by the recurrence relation.  Also, `hw` stands for "half-width":  half the width allocated for printing a number, and `pad` is a strict left-pad that truncates the output rather than disrupt the formatting.